# Button alignment is ugly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, login

An alignment of the Login and Cancel button is ugly in http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ confirm login screen

See

[image]

Comment: Pushing a fix now. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

You should see this changed with our next build today. Thanks for catching it.